# Dynamical effects of the scale invariance of the empty space: The fall of dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy

André Maeder, Honorary Professor in the Department of Astronomy of the Faculty of Science at the University of Geneva (UNIGE) believes that the commonly accepted model of the Big Bang followed by an expansion, which uses dark matter and dark energy, does not take into account the "scale invariance of the empty space".

This expression means that the vacuum and its properties do not change as a result of expansion or contraction: "When we add the hypothesis of the scale invariance of the empty space, we see a very very small term of outward acceleration that opposes the gravitational force," explained Maeder.

On Earth, this term is insignificant, but in very sparse environments, like the edges of a galaxy or clusters of galaxies, it becomes relatively important. It thus makes it possible to account for the high speeds of stars on the borders of a galaxy.

In clusters made up of hundreds of galaxies, the movements observed are faster than what the visible mass would allow. Professor Maeder also finds that his model predicts the acceleration of the expansion of the Universe without any particle or ounce of dark energy being needed.

Ref: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.11425

My question is the same as the one raised by Pr. André Maeder:

Could this indeed be the fall of dark matter ?

EDIT

The Maeder model, if validated, would solves two of astronomy’s greatest mysteries, 80 years after the contribution of Fritz Zwicky (Swiss as well).

This topic has been put on hold by some moderator.

Myself physicist (University of Geneva), but having worked in others fields, I would have find interesting to hear from those active in the field on what seems to me to be the fall of the dark matter and dark energy. I would appreciate allowing the discussion to happen.

Comment: How dare you to say this on the dark matter dominated forum!

Comment: As interesting as these ideas may be, this does strike me as something that's going to be opinion based.

Comment: I see a basic error, and would not doubt others exist. The idea that empty space is conformally symmetric, because outside galaxies it's mostly empty space, only dark energy, which is a microscopic (vacuum energy) effect and can be ignored macroscopically. It can't, the Friedman equations are for a model with average matter, rad and dark energy densities. Using the solution in those regions assuming those are zero is faulty logic and easy to skip over. The Lambda is part of the average density, can't set to zero. I can't tell if published at Ap.J., or just submitted. I'm guessing other errors

Comment: This paper is a fantastic example of how the idiots (and there are plenty use this forum) that think there is some sort of conspiracy belong with other tinfoil-wearing conspiracy theorists. This is properly done science getting published (it is in ApJ  iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aa92cc/pdf) in proper peer-reviewed journals. Whether it is right or wrong remains to be seen, though note that it addresses only a limited fraction of the phenomenology that dark matter current "explains". Having said that, *this* is a question that can only invite opinion-based answers.

Comment: I am not an expert, but this sounds similar to http://estfound.org/ - C. Johan Masreliez theory, which uses 5th dimension time-space scale factor and also claims to explain cosmological phenomena, deduce both QM and GR from simple first principles.

Comment: FYI: the question was **not** closed by a moderator. It was closed by five regular users.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Each web site has its rules. I just regret that here, an open discussion is not allowed but I accept it very well.

Comment: @HeyStackExchange Every venue has a certain scope, and [this venue is not a substitute for peer review](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7516/); more generally, there are some forms of open-ended discussion that don't fit here because this site is in a Q&A format, not a discussion forum. There's plenty of discussion of the (extreme lack of) merits of Meader's claims at e.g. [Backreaction](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2017/11/astrophysicist-discovers-yet-another.html) and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it could be the fall of dark matter. Or, [mimetic gravity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07290) might be the fall of dark matter. Or, [conformal gravity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2186) might be the fall of dark matter. Or, [there might be dark matter](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1839).

Comment: -1 In other words, the answer could be anything. I think this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, it coudn't be. [Hossenfelder writes on Backreaction blog](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2017/11/astrophysicist-discovers-yet-another.html):"*For those of you who merely want to know whether you should pay attention to this new variant of modified gravity, the answer is no. The author does not have a consistent theory. The math is wrong... You shouldn’t be surprised that he can fit some observations when you put in the scale of the cosmological constant to galactic models, because we have known this link since the 1980s.*" This was quick.